# PHP: Find the index of an item in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to find the current index of an item in an array but I'm hitting some walls. I need it to come back non-zero indexed as well but can't put my finger on it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Array Example**

```
$portfolioArray = array(    
    'name1' => array(
      'img' => 'foo',
      'url' => 'bar',
      'title' => 'foo bar',
    ),
    'name2' => array(
      'img' => 'foo',
      'url' => 'bar',
      'title' => 'foo bar',
    ),
    'name3' => array(
      'img' => 'foo',
      'url' => 'bar',
      'title' => 'foo bar',
    ),
    ...
);
```

**Where I'm Calling It**

```
  $project = 'name2';
  $id = HERE I WANT TO FIND THE INDEX FOR NAME2
  $prevId = $id-1;
  $nextId = $id+1;
```

Basically, I want to know if the $project variable is the 2nd, 15th, or 1034587th in the list.

Help?

Comment: So you want to get 1 here as result ? OR what would be the expected output here?

Comment: [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Comment: How long do you expect this array to become? If it would remain small it would be possible to just do this with a loop, if you expect this to become, like you said a list with 1034587 items I'd advice against.

Comment: @Rizier123, Just needed to get what number in the array it is. The answer below was correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
<?php
$portfolioArray = array(    
    'name1' => array(
      'img' => 'foo',
      'url' => 'bar',
      'title' => 'foo bar',
    ),
    'name2' => array(
      'img' => 'foo',
      'url' => 'bar',
      'title' => 'foo bar',
    ),
    'name3' => array(
      'img' => 'foo',
      'url' => 'bar',
      'title' => 'foo bar',
    )
);

echo array_search("name2", array_keys($portfolioArray));
?>
```

More info about the functions used:

http://php.net/array_search

http://php.net/array_keys

Comment: Perfect! Does it exactly what I need.
I had $id = array_search('name2',$portfolioArray);. Close but so far away.